# append csv with dataframe row delimited with pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I previously did this:

```
dfx.to_csv('test.csv', index=None, sep='|')
```

I want to append that file with another dataframe. Here is my attempt:

```
with open('test.csv','a') as fd:
        fd.write(str(dfx.iloc[0]))
```

The new dataframe I want to append to the csv only has one row of data in it and it needs to be pipe delimited.

EDIT: nothing happens

EDIT2: I have to add a row to the already existing csv. The CSV is created completely separately. I show it here so you know how I am creating it so it can be appended correctly, not because it is happening in the same script etc.

EDIT3: This gets me what I want to append with:

```
s = dfx.iloc[0]
print(s.str.cat(sep='|'))
```

But this doesn't append as expected:

```
with open('test.csv','a') as fd:
            fd.write(str(s))
```

EDIT4: this worked:

```
        # Save periodicity to csv the first time
#         dfx.to_csv('test.csv', index=None, sep='|')

        # append the csv
        s = dfx.iloc[0]
#         print(s.str.cat(sep='|'))
        s = s.str.cat(sep='|')
        with open('test.csv','a') as fd:
            fd.write(str(s) + '\n')
```

Comment: Please clarify: a) `dfx` is `pandas.DataFrame`? b) if so: are you aware of `DataFrame.concat`?

Comment: a) it is, b) no, new to py

Comment: i don't want to append the dataframe. I want to append the csv

Comment: "I want to append that file with another dataframe" - I suggest you think about: a) [concatenating](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) dataframes and then `to_csv` concatenated result, b) concatenate string outputs of `to_csv`

Comment: I can't. I have to add a row to an existing csv.

Comment: You can concatenate string output of `to_csv`. Look at my answer. Is it what you need?

Comment: Please add examples of input and desired format of output csv. I thought that I understood you but I was mistaken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188911/discussion-between-alex-yu-and-mountainclimber).

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote that you want concatenate csv-files I suggest:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("x,y,z\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n"))
df2=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("x,y,z\n4,6,4\n5,5,5\n"))

with open('/tmp/the_csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv(index=False,header=True, sep='|'))

with open('/tmp/the_csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv(index=False,header=False, sep='|'))
```

**Check content:**

`!cat /tmp/the_csv`

```
x|y|z
1|2|3
4|5|6
1|2|3
4|5|6
```